# How to limit upload files in dropzone.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js, stimulusjs

I have ruby on rails application with stimulus.js and dropzone.js for uploading attachment. There is now a limit on uploading one file, but this allows you to upload more than one file and just shows an error message on them. I need that it is not possible to upload more than one file and if after that the user tries to upload another one, a replacement occurs.

dropzone_controller.js

```
import Dropzone from "dropzone";
import { Controller } from "stimulus";
import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage";
import {
  getMetaValue,
  toArray,
  findElement,
  removeElement,
  insertAfter
} from "helpers";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["input"];

  connect() {
    this.dropZone = createDropZone(this);
    this.hideFileInput();
    this.bindEvents();
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; // necessary quirk for Dropzone error in console
  }

  // Private
  hideFileInput() {
    this.inputTarget.disabled = true;
    this.inputTarget.style.display = "none";
  }

  bindEvents() {
    this.dropZone.on("addedfile", file => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        file.accepted && createDirectUploadController(this, file).start();
      }, 500);
    });

    this.dropZone.on("removedfile", file => {
      file.controller && removeElement(file.controller.hiddenInput);
    });

    this.dropZone.on("canceled", file => {
      file.controller && file.controller.xhr.abort();
    });
  }

  get headers() {
    return { "X-CSRF-Token": getMetaValue("csrf-token") };
  }

  get url() {
    return this.inputTarget.getAttribute("data-direct-upload-url");
  }

  get maxFiles() {
    return this.data.get("maxFiles") || 1;
  }

  get maxFileSize() {
    return this.data.get("maxFileSize") || 256;
  }

  get acceptedFiles() {
    return this.data.get("acceptedFiles");
  }

  get addRemoveLinks() {
    return this.data.get("addRemoveLinks") || true;
  }
}

class DirectUploadController {
  constructor(source, file) {
    this.directUpload = createDirectUpload(file, source.url, this);
    this.source = source;
    this.file = file;
  }

  start() {
    this.file.controller = this;
    this.hiddenInput = this.createHiddenInput();
    this.directUpload.create((error, attributes) => {
      if (error) {
        removeElement(this.hiddenInput);
        this.emitDropzoneError(error);
      } else {
        this.hiddenInput.value = attributes.signed_id;
        this.emitDropzoneSuccess();
      }
    });
  }

  createHiddenInput() {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = this.source.inputTarget.name;
    insertAfter(input, this.source.inputTarget);
    return input;
  }

  directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR(xhr) {
    this.bindProgressEvent(xhr);
    this.emitDropzoneUploading();
  }

  bindProgressEvent(xhr) {
    this.xhr = xhr;
    this.xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", event =>
      this.uploadRequestDidProgress(event)
    );
  }

  uploadRequestDidProgress(event) {
    const element = this.source.element;
    const progress = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    findElement(
      this.file.previewTemplate,
      ".dz-upload"
    ).style.width = `${progress}%`;
  }

  emitDropzoneUploading() {
    this.file.status = Dropzone.UPLOADING;
    this.source.dropZone.emit("processing", this.file);
  }

  emitDropzoneError(error) {
    this.file.status = Dropzone.ERROR;
    this.source.dropZone.emit("error", this.file, error);
    this.source.dropZone.emit("complete", this.file);
  }

  emitDropzoneSuccess() {
    this.file.status = Dropzone.SUCCESS;
    this.source.dropZone.emit("success", this.file);
    this.source.dropZone.emit("complete", this.file);
  }
}

function createDirectUploadController(source, file) {
  return new DirectUploadController(source, file);
}

function createDirectUpload(file, url, controller) {
  return new DirectUpload(file, url, controller);
}

function createDropZone(controller) {
  return new Dropzone(controller.element, {
    url: controller.url,
    headers: controller.headers,
    maxFiles: controller.maxFiles,
    maxFilesize: controller.maxFileSize,
    acceptedFiles: controller.acceptedFiles,
    addRemoveLinks: controller.addRemoveLinks,
    autoQueue: false
  });
}
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div data-lite-visibility-target="dynamic" class="space-y-8 <%= @automate_task_report.attachment.present? ? '' : "hidden" %>" >
            <div class="form-group inverted">
              <%= form.label :attachment, "Upload test execution results", class: "form-label" %>
              <button type="button" class="dropzone dropzone-default dz-clickable form-control form-file form-file-btn" data-controller="dropzone" data-dropzone-max-file-size="10" data-dropzone-max-files="1" data-dropzone-accepted-files=".xml,.html,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif">
                <%= form.file_field :attachment, direct_upload: true, data: { target: 'dropzone.input' } %>
                <div class="dropzone-msg dz-message needsclick flex m-0">
                  <% if @automate_task_report.attachment.attached? %>
                    <%= form.hidden_field :attachment, value: @automate_task_report.attachment.signed_id %>
                    <div class="mx-5 attachment vertical">
                      <%= link_to @automate_task_report.attachment, target: "_blank", class:"attachment-thumb" do %>
                        <%= image_tag(@automate_task_report.attachment) %>
                      <% end %>
                      <%= link_to @automate_task_report.attachment.filename.to_s, @automate_task_report.attachment, target: "_blank", class:"attachment-name" %>
                      <%= link_to @automate_task_report.attachment, download: @automate_task_report.attachment, class:"btn btn-primary attachment-btn" do %>
                        <span class="icon text-icon-default icon-download"></span>
                      <% end %>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>
                  <span class="icon text-icon-lg icon-file-image-plus-lg mr-3"></span>
                  <div class="text-left mt-0">
                    <p>Upload a file or drag and drop</p>
                    <p class="text-xs">XML, HTML, PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I'm already tried things like

```
= {
   maxFiles: 1
};
```

but it didn't work for me. How can I achive expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "accept" callback to check for the max amount of files:

```js
accept: function(file, done) {
    if (/* do a check here */) {
        done(error message);
        // File is cancel.
        file.status = Dropzone.CANCELED;
    }
}
```

key point here is change the file status to cancelled to let dropzone know about it